# Displacing location while iterating through vector

Tags: c++, c++11

How can you displace the location you iterate through a vector?  I've tried something like:

```
for(auto x : vect+2)
```

but this doesn't work.  I'm sure there's a simple resolve, but I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: What do you mean by "displace"? Iterate through 0, 2, 4, etc?

Comment: Start from location 2, and iterate by one, for example.

Comment: Do you want to use an iterator, or an index?

Comment: Instead of doing index++ do index+=2

Comment: Just use a normal `for` loop? EDIT: See Andy's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the range-based `for`, you could use [**Boost.Range**](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/) to create a range that starts from the third element of your vector (`begin() + 2`):

```
for (auto x : boost::make_iterator_range(begin(v) + 2, end(v)))
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);

    for (auto x : boost::make_iterator_range(begin(v) + 2, end(v)))
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

If you want to loop through every second element, instead, you could change your range as follows:

```
namespace rng = boost::adaptors;
for (auto x : v | rng::strided(2))
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Which in a full program would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace rng = boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> v(10);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);

    for (auto x : v | rng::strided(2))
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

Boost.Range is pretty flexible, so you can for instance *combine* the two adapters above:

```
for (auto x : boost::make_iterator_range(begin(v) + 2, end(v)) |
              rng::strided(3))
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

---

If you do not want or cannot use Boost, you could use a classical `for` loop with iterators:

```
for (auto i = begin(v) + 2; i != end(v); ++i)
{
    std::cout << *i << " ";
}
```

This is how the whole program would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    iota(begin(v), end(v), 1);

    for (auto i = begin(v) + 2; i != end(v); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved very simply, and has a number of solutions to suit any programming style.

## The Classical Approach

```
int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

    for (auto i = v.begin() + 2; i != v.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
}
```

## The Functional Approach

```
int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

    std::for_each(v.begin() + 2, v.end(), [](int val)
        {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Opinion: Range `for`s don't add anything to the language; don't bother using them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a light wrapper to make it work with range-based for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

namespace range
{
    template <typename C>
    struct make_range
    {
        C t;
        make_range(C t, int offset)
        : t(std::begin(t) + offset, std::end(t))
        {}
        auto begin() -> decltype(t.begin())
        {
            return t.begin();
        }
        auto end() -> decltype(t.end())
        {
            return t.end();
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    for (auto i : range::make_range<decltype(v)>(v, 2))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Perhaps it would be better to just store the iterators:

```
namespace range
{
    template <typename C>
    struct make_range
    {
        typename C::iterator beg_iter;
        typename C::iterator end_iter;
        make_range(C& t, int offset)
        : beg_iter(std::begin(t) + offset),  end_iter(std::end(t))
        {}
        auto begin() -> decltype(beg_iter)
        {
            return beg_iter;
        }
        auto end() -> decltype(end_iter)
        {
            return end_iter;
        }
    };
}
```